# Effects of the removal of K&R function definitions in C2x

Tags: c

One of the changes for the upcoming C2x standard seems to be the

> Removal of K&R function definitions

From what i understand the K&R style definitions is the reason why we have to declare a function that takes no parameters as

```
void foo(void);
```

instead of

```
void foo();
```

Does the removal of the K&R style in C2x mean we can/should now simply use empty brackets for functions that are taking no paramers like in other languages?

Comment: The opposite is true as far as I can tell...

Comment: The need for `(void)` only applies to function declarations that are not also definitions.  For definitions like you show `()` and `(void)` are identical.

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes, you are right, i edited the two snippets in my question. I was asking about declarations.

Comment: `seems to be the` Could you post the source of the information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

K&R style function definitions are things like

```
int foo(a, b)
int a;
int b;
{
    /* function body here*/
```

They are completely orthogonal to the question of `(void)` vs `()` in a function declaration

Answer (score 5):

Here is Section 6.7.6.3 (Function declarators) item 13 of the [Working Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf) as of Dec, 2020:

> For a function declarator without a parameter type list: if it is part of a definition of that function
> the function has no parameters and the effect is as if it were declared with a parameter type list
> consisting of the keyword void; otherwise it specifies that no information about the number or types
> of the parameters is supplied.157) A function declarator provides a prototype for the function if it
> includes a parameter type list.158) Otherwise, a function declaration is said to have no prototype.

So in a function definition, you will be able to omit `(void)`, but you still have to include it in a function declaration.